# Objects out of XML from Server Optimal Design

Tags: xml, parsing, haxe, server

I need to parse XML for my Haxe game from server responses/requests.

The game flow depends on this data and I will put this data into objects. There are a lot of flags and objects to be used.

I know I can parse with the FAST XML library in Haxe but I want to avoid this kind of thing all over my code:

```
if ( response.node.ABC.node.EFG.node.HIJ.nodes.ABCState == "xyz" ) {
//blah
}
```

There must be a better way! Can I used typdefs? Does anyone have a better idea than just tedious node access all over the place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the "selecthxml" library:

http://lib.haxe.org/p/selecthxml

https://code.google.com/p/selecthxml/wiki/TypedXml

It turns Xml into typedef'd objects using macros. I haven't used the full feature set but it seems close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another library for serializing/unserializing haxe objects to/from xml:

https://github.com/submain/cereal

Maybe that can give you what you need.